# Laravel {{Form::Select}} not passing values to POST request parameters

Tags: php, post, parameters, request, laravel-5

this problem occured recently on a website on my development server, which runs Laravel 5.2.45. I have a form which I use to pass data through a POST request on a controller. On the form there are 2 multiselects, one for the available locations and one for the selected locations. The user can pass a location from the available locations to the selected locations. The problem is that once the form submits, the selected locations do not appear anywhere on the request parameters, but the available locations appear. This was working for a long time and suddendly it stopped working.

***Available locations multiselect***

```
<div class="form-group clearfix{{ $errors->has('available') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
{!! Form::label('available', 'Available Locations', ['class'=> 'col-xs-12 pl-0 pr-0']) !!}
<div class="col-xs-12 pl-0 pr-0">
    {{Form::select('available[]', $taskgroup['available'], null, ['id'=> 'multiselect', 'class'=> 'form-control', 'size'=> 8, 'multiple' => 'multiple']) }}
</div>
@if ($errors->has('available'))
<span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('available') }}</span>
@endif
```

***Selected locations multiselect***

```
<div class="form-group clearfix{{ $errors->has('locations') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
{!! Form::label('locations', 'Selected Locations', ['class'=> 'col-xs-12 pl-0 pr-0']) !!}
<div class="col-xs-12 pl-0 pr-0">
    {{Form::select('locations[]', $taskgroup['locations'], null, ['id'=> 'multiselect_to', 'class'=> 'form-control', 'size'=> 8, 'multiple' => 'multiple']) }}
</div>
@if ($errors->has('locations'))
<span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('locations') }}</span>
@endif
```

***The part which handles the request in the controller***

```
$taskgroup = Taskgroup::with('locations')->findOrFail($id);
    $input = Input::all();
    //dd($request,$input);
    unset($input['available']);
    if(!empty(array_values($input['media_url'])[0]['title'])){
        $media_url = Taskgroup::sortArray($input['media_url'], 'order');
        $input['media_url'] = json_encode(array('media' => $media_url));
    } else {
        unset($input['media_url']);
    }
    $messages = ['between' => 'The :attribute must be between :min - :max.'];
    $validation = Validator::make($input, array_merge(Taskgroup::$rules, array('locations'=>'required|between:1,'.$input['max_users'])), $messages);
```

***The uncommented data dump of the input data***

```
"_method" => "PUT"
"_token" => "Token Here"
"name" => "Beer"
"short_description" => "Short Description<br>"
"_wysihtml5_mode" => "1"
"long_description" => "<div>Long Description</div>"
"pin_color" => "red"
"start_date" => "2018-12-03 09:00"
"end_date" => "2019-12-31 20:00"
"media_url" => array:1
"file_names" => array:1
"delete-file-85" => "0"
"delete-file-86" => "0"
"max_users" => "32"
"max_arrival_time" => "120"
"max_completion_time" => "30"
"client_id" => "22"
"q" => ""
"available" => array:977
"files" => array:1
```

This is my first post on the website, so please excuse any formatting errors. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's strange that it stopped working suddenly. Have you checked your html code (view your page source and make sure the element is indeed included in the form) ??

Comment: @Andreas I've checked the source before posting here and I've verified that the element is included in the form. It should be noted that the only thing I've changed is the size of the multiselect element from 8 to 40, but I fail to see why this change should result in such a behavior. I reverted that change but the problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
{!!Form::select(....)!!}
```

Comment: Apologies, I should have mentioned that I have already done that and it didn't work.